# Firefox error message when opening web page from Java

Tags: java, firefox, ubuntu-14.04

I get an unusual error message when I open a web page from a Java program in Firefox version 54.0. The error occurs when I run the program using Ubuntu 14.04. The error does not occur when running the same version of Firefox with MacOS 10.12.5 or Windows 10.

The source code for opening the web page is:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Desktop;

class Example
  {  
   public static void main(String args[])
     {
      System.out.println(">>> Example Start");  
      try
        { openWebpage(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com")); }
      catch (Exception e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }
      System.out.println("<<< Example End");  
     }  

    public static void openWebpage(URL url) 
      {
       Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
       if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) 
         {
          try
            {
             URI uri = url.toURI(); 
             desktop.browse(uri); 
            } 
          catch (Exception e)
            { e.printStackTrace(); }
         }
      }
  }
```

The error I get:

```
$ javac Example.java
$ java Example
>>> Example Start
<<< Example End

(firefox:20377): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:20377): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:20377): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:20377): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
$
```

I don't see the same error when I use Chromium as the default browser.

Comment: There appears to be trouble with those messages (not just with Firefox) by other users, see this:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1582496 ... One user mentions similar Firefox errors at that link back around mid-December.